# React - Converting Class to Function Components For Front-End

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, blockchain, solidity

I've been working on converting a simple yield farming DAPP from class to function components.

So far so good for loading the contracts and getting the data, but I'm stuck on two pieces - the part where I call the staking smart contract's deposit function, and how I can initiate that from my button.

This is working entirely in the class components, but not the function conversation. I'll paste the class/function versions both for comparison.

I've been going through the react documentation and trying to fill in the gaps with pure testing, but have not been able to get past this last part of updating the codebase.

Any insights into what I'm missing here?

REACT FUNCTION CALLING STAKING SMART CONTRACT FUNCTION

Class Comp. Version:

```
stakeTokensVault = (amount) => {
    this.setState({loading: true })
    this.state.tether.methods.approve(this.state.chadsVault._address, amount).send({from: this.state.account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
      this.state.chadsVault.methods.stake(amount).send({from: this.state.account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.setState({loading:false})
      })
    }) 
  }
```

Function Comp. Version:

```
function stakeTokensVault(amount) {
    // this.setState({loading: true })
    tether.methods.approve(chadsVault._address, amount).send({from: account[0]}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
      chadsVault.methods.stake(amount).send({from: account[0]}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        // this.setState({loading:false})
      })
    }) 
  }
```

UI BUTTON FOR CALLING DEPOSIT FUNCTION

Class Comp. Version:

```
<input class="form-control" ref={(input)=> {this.input = input} } id="exampleInputText1" type="text" placeholder="Amount" required />
                                <button 
                                    type='submit'
                                    onClick={(event) => {
                                    event.preventDefault()
                                    let amount
                                    amount = this.input.value.toString()
                                    amount = window.web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'Ether')
                                    this.props.stakeTokensVault(amount)
                                    }}
                                    className='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>DEPOSIT
                                </button>
```

Function Comp. Version:

```
<input type="number" ref={inputRef} className="form-control" />
                                
                                <button 
                                    type='submit'
                                    onClick={(event) => {
                                    event.preventDefault()
                                    let amount
                                    amount = inputRef.value.toString() 
                                    amount = window.web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'Ether')
                                    props.stakeTokensVault(amount)
                                    }}
                                    className='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>DEPOSIT
                                </button>
```

Currently for the function comp. version, as displayed in the code above, I'm getting the error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')."

Comment: For the first error, you were using `this.state.account`, so the value converted to hooks should be `[account, setAccount] = useState()` and the variable `account`, maybe not `account[0]` like you are doing.
The last error is because `inputRef.value` is `null`. IIRC, it is now called `inputRef.current`, you could log that out to confirm. Bear in mind that the ref is always `null` on first render.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my working version below for those who reference this post for the same or similar issues.

**Input form w/ button:**

```
<input type="number" ref={inputRef} className="form-control" />
                                
                                <button 
                                    type='submit'
                                    onClick={(event) => {
                                    event.preventDefault()
                                    let amount
                                    amount = inputRef.current.value.toString() 
                                    amount = window.web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'Ether')
                                    props.stakeTokensVault(amount)
                                    }}
                                    className='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'>DEPOSIT
                                </button>
```

And the staking/deposit function:

```
const stakeTokensVault = (amount) => {
  
    tether.methods.approve(chadsVault._address, amount).send({from: account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
    chadsVault.methods.stake(amount).send({from: account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
   
    })
  })
}
```